# JAVA. How to create method with variable from another scope in Java

Tags: java, string, swing, scope

I've started writing my own Java program during my freetime called the "Book A Ticket Machine", it's a Java console program with no GUI. It will Ask you for your FullName, FrequentFlyer ID, Age, then match you to your designated airline and flight number. While you travel your fuel will decrease and when it lands the fuel will fill up (I will create a fill method for this). I am having problems with calling a method from outside a scope.

Currently I have two files:

1. `Flights.java` --> Launching file. Linked with flightUserDatabase.
2. `flightUserDatabase.java` --> Contains all methods and class/blueprints all username, age, frequentFlyer, etc.

Code from Flights.java:

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Flights {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
      Console console = System.console();
      //Book a Ticket Machine
      //From Database otherwise Name not found on Database. Put Database in Another Class. Call it flightUserDatabase.
      /* firstName: DONE
         lastName: DONE
         frequentFlyerID: Otherwise Invalid Number parseInt
         Age: parseInt
         FUEL MINUS AND FUEL ADD WHEN LAND.
      */

      flightUserDatabase database = new flightUserDatabase();

      System.out.println("Enter Creditials:  ");
      database.getDatabase();

      String airline = console.readLine("ENTER YOUR AIRLINE:  ");
      String flightNumber = console.readLine("ENTER YOUR FLIGHT NUMBER:  ");
      String gate = "B7"; /* Declare data type String called "gate" */ 
     //Next Version, Generate Random Number

      System.out.println("This is an automated system. Please Wait...");
      System.out.printf("%s %s is Departuring @ Gate:%s \n", airline, flightNumber, gate); /* Use printf from java.io.Console library, then output Gate and Flight Number */



      /* Notes: Data Types
      > String name = "Ohm";
      > int age = 42;
      > double score = 95.5;
      > char group = 'F';
      */
    }

}
```

Code from `flightUserDatabase.java`:

```
import java.io.Console;
  //Book a Ticket Machine

class flightUserDatabase {
    Console console = System.console();
    public String fullName;

    public boolean getDatabase() {
    boolean namesInDatabase;
    do {
    fullName = console.readLine("ENTER YOUR FULLNAME:  ");
    namesInDatabase = (fullName.equals("Ohm Passavudh") || fullName.equals("Matt"));

    if (!namesInDatabase) {
      console.printf("Sorry, that name is not in our database yet. \n");
    }
    if (namesInDatabase) {
      console.printf("Welcome, Mr. %s \n", fullName); 
    }
    } while(!namesInDatabase);
    return namesInDatabase;
    }
    //If Ohm: FFID = 1234569 
    //If Matt: FFID = 246810
    //FFID == FrequentFlyerID
    /* Get name from inside scope fullName namesInDatabase variable  */


      public boolean frequentFlyerID()


I HAVE PROBLEMS HERE!!! I WANT TO SET Ohm's FFID to 1234569. But how to I determine if the user enters Ohm or Matt. I cannot access the String fullName from the other scope. I hope you understand me. If there is any misunderstanding I can clarify. 
 }
```

Comment: Unreadable code.  I'd recommend that as a beginner you think more about style, readability, and decomposition.  Objects should do one thing well.  Your FlightDatabase should not be performing I/O operations or prompting users for input.  Where is the class for Passenger?  You need one.

Answer (score 0):

First, please, do work on your formatting, reading that code was awful.

You can create a class field and a getter in flightUserDatabase, so you can get the name after you've determined the name is in the database.

Or you can return it with getDatabase()

Like this...

```
public String getDatabase()
{
  String fullName;
  ...
  return fullName;
}
```

After all, you're not using that boolean.

... or this ...

```
class flightUserDatabase
{
  private String fullName = "";
  ...
  public String getName()
  {
    return this.fullName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to initialize variable `public String fullName;` -> `public String fullName = "";`
2. Work on formating code
3. Name class begin from upper sign in your case FlightUserDatabase
4. Remember about encapsulation (private variable)